# ${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES} returns Qt5::Core instead of a list to the actual libraries

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5

It's convenient to just use `target_link_libraries(MyExecutable Qt5::Core)`, but when I do `message(STATUS "Qt5Core_LIBRARIES=${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES}")` I would expect it to return something like `/opt/Qt/<...>/libQt5Core.so;/opt/<...>.so;[etc]` instead of `Qt5::Core`.  That doesn't really help me at all.  Any way to get the actual list of libraries?

Thanks in advance! (Long time lurker, first time asker.)

Answer (score 2):

Qt5::Core is an IMPORTED target, which has target_properties like any other target. I'd assume the property INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES would give you what you seek.